# Does the direction of a dependency connector matter in UML?

Tags: uml

I have come across several examples of dependencies e.g. include, extend however it is utterly confusing. One example dictates that `include` should be in the direction of;

```
user profile --> login
```

Whilst `extends` should be in the direction of;

```
validate credit card <-- print receipt.
```

Whereas `required` should in the direction of; For the life of me I don't get why this can't be an `include`

```
place order --> create account
```

Also does it matter how these are constructed i.e.

```
user profile --> login (include)

      **vs**

validate credit card (extend)
       ^
       |
       |
       |
  print receipt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand every part of your questions, but here we go:

An include goes from the including to the included. It denotes a mandatory sub part of the use case :

```
including -----------> included
          <<include>>
```

Extend is the same than include, but the sub part is not mandatory. And unfortunately, the arrow is the other way around. Which seems to puzzle you a lot.

```
including <----------- optionnally included
            <<extend>>
```

When you speak about required, I suppose it is an anonymous dashed arrow? In fact, such a dependency can be written for anything, use case or not. It is not that usual for use cases, but it could mean that a use case has another as a prerequisite. Difference with include is that it is not a sub part. In this case, it is drawn this way.

```
requiring -----------> required
```

In your example, it seems that to place an order, you must have created an account (logical indeed). But account creation is not a sub part of order placing, so it is not an include.

As for your last question, are you talking about vertical/horizontal? If so, it does not matter in UML. In fact, there is no rule about positioning, the only rule is to remain clear.